# Compiling default package / top-level functions into a SWC

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, compilation, flashdevelop, swc

Are custom functions that are defined at the "default" package level (aka Top Level) included in a compiled SWC? Or are they ignored?

```
//Compiled, or not to be compiled in a SWC - that is the question...

package {
  public function topLevelMethod():void {
    trace("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Anyone experienced problems with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is yes, they are included when compiled into the SWC. Whether the method is at the top-level or deeper in a package-level, it's treated no differently than a Class (in terms of being included / excluded, at least some research should be done to find out they can be enumerated in an -load-extern file).

*PS.: Yes I've answered this myself - I have done the **stupid mistake** of placing my SWC in the 'bin' folder instead of my 'libs' folder (to overwrite the old one), so no wonder I was never seeing my top-level methods!*

Answer (score 0):

If you're compiling your SWC with Flash Builder you can manage included classes in project properties > Flex Library Build Path > Classes.

Comment: I'm using FlashDevelop unfortunately. Are you sure what you're point out will also compile top-level Methods? I'm not talking about Classes, just "bare naked" methods that can be used anywhere globally.

Comment: Sorry I didn't ever use FlashDevelop and have no thoughts about its compile options :(

Comment: No Problem. I think I realized I was doing something wrong... I'll post an update / self-answer shortly.